# Session info lost using React-Router navigating two ajax calls in react components

Tags: ajax, session, authentication, reactjs, react-router

I am new here. Would like to seek your help for the problem that blocks me several days.

The design is simple. I have a server.js running localhost. It provides a POST (Login to acquire authentication) and a GET method (retrieving json after authentication). The login uses basic authentication to verify email/password of a user. if matches, return status 200 and put the user in the session & response. The following are the server side codes:

---

```
//Log user in Server.js  
app.post('/session/login', function(req, res) {  
  var email = req.body.email;  
  var password = req.body.password;

  if ( null == email || email.length < 1
  || null == password || password.length < 1 ) {  
res.status(401).send("Wrong username or password");
return;
  }

  if (email == "xxxxx" && password == "xxxxx") {  
var user = new User(email, password);      
req.session.user = user;  
  return res.status(200).send({
    auth : true,
    user : user
  });
}else{  
  return res.status(401).send("Wrong username or password");
}
});
```

---

The Get Method is having a basic auth before server can pass the json back. The following are the codes:

---

```
function Auth (req, res, next) {  
  if(req.session.user){  
next();
  }else{  
    console.log("Auth");  
res.status(401).send({
  flash : 'Please log in first'
    });
  }
}


app.get('/form/FormFields', Auth, function(req, res) {  
  fs.readFile(FORMFIELDS_FILE, function(err, data) {  
  if (err) {
console.error(err);
process.exit(1);
  }  
  res.json(JSON.parse(data));
  });
});
```

---

Now client side, I have two js files, one is a form to email/password to call Login above, and the other is simply get the form info using ajax in react. The navigation uses React-Router. The following are some codes:

---

```
// login.js
var LoginBox = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {text: '', data: []};
  },
  handleLoginSubmit: function (data) {
$.ajax({
  url: "https://localhost:3000/session/login",
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
    });
  },    
  render: function () {
return(
  <div className="container">
    <LoginForm data={this.state.data} onLoginSubmit={this.handleLoginSubmit} />
    <p className="tips">{this.state.text}</p>
  </div>
);
  }

});

var LoginForm = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  },  
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {data:0,tittle: 'Login Test',text:''};
  },
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
    var password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    if (!email || !password) {
      this.setState({text:"please input both username and password!"});
      return;
    }
    this.props.onLoginSubmit({email:email,password:password});
    this.setState({text:""});
    this.refs.email.value = '';
    this.refs.password.value = '';

    //Routing defined in React-Router
    const path = '/form';
    this.context.router.push(path);
  },
  render: function () {
      return (
    <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <p>{this.state.tittle}</p>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your username" ref="email"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Your password" ref="password"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
      <p className="tips">{this.state.text}</p>
    </form>
  )
  }
});


//code piece in form.js to call server and get form info

loadFieldsFromServer: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "https://localhost:3000/form/FormFields",
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
  },
```

---

Eventually, here is my problem. the login is ok, which I can see from network monitoring. I printed the log in server and found user is saved in the session. However when it navigates to form.js, I always retrieve 401 from server code below. from the log, i found user info in the session disappears and hence the following 401 returns.

```
else{
console.log("Auth");
res.status(401).send({
  flash : 'Please log in first'
});
```

}

Please anybody help take a look at where i am wrong. Many thanks. BTW, just share more info, when I use Postman to simulate two calls to the server. Once I call login first, I can also retrieve form json successfully unless i call logout to clean the user in the session. Just dont know why it does not work in the program.

Comment: Did you know that if you set `req.session` in one request, it won't be available to other requests (how would the server know who the request is coming from). Unless you're storing a cookie in the browser. Are you? If not, maybe take a look at [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: @DavidGilbertson, many thanks for your reply and I think it is the reason each HTTP request is stateless. I will store it in the cookie and have a try. Just curious to know why it works in the Postman

Comment: I am also curious to know why it works in postman :) It should not.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson, I had a try yesterday and had a follow up problem found. I checked the network monitoring and I did find the cookie sent to the client side after login success, as below:      set-cookie: connect.sid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Path=/; HttpOnly            however, when I took a look at the second call request header, I didn't see the cookie info in the request. As suggested, I am supposed to use the cookie info in request of second call to do authorization in server side. So do i need to explicitly do some codes in second call to send cookie in request?

Comment: All cookies (for your domain) are sent with every single request, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: then that's weird. no cookie info was sent in the request header of my second call. anybody had same problem?